# JavaFX 8 isCancelled without a while loop

Tags: service, javafx, task

I am trying to run another Java program from within my JavaFX GUI. On clicking the Start button, the program runs fine and shows the progress on 
the GUI as expected. However, clicking the Cancel button cancels the service and prints state as CANCELLED but never triggers the "setOnCancelled" event and doesn't cancel the task.  The "main" backend program is continuing to run.

All the examples I have come across so far on canceling a Task use a while loop to find the task.isCancelled state. I am wondering how I can find it without using a while loop, or create a while loop just for the sake of it but still run my program only once (without triggering it multiple times within that loop).  Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code snippet

```
    // Event Listener on Button[#startCompareButton].onAction
    @FXML
    public void startCompare(ActionEvent event) 

    startCompareButton.setDisable(true);
    cancelCompareButton.setDisable(false);

    fileCompare = new FileCompareFx();

    // pass gui progress controls to the backend program to display progress
    fileCompare.setGUIControls(/* arguments */ );

    service = new Service<Boolean>() {

      @Override
      protected Task<Boolean> createTask() {
        return new Task<Boolean>() {
          @Override
          protected Boolean call() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

            // can be a very long running process. should enable user to cancel

            fileCompare.main(/* folderName */ );

            Boolean returnValue = true;
            return returnValue;
          }
        };
      }

    };

    service.setOnCancelled(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

      @Override
      public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
        System.out.println("In setOnCancelled");
        /* the backend program should have terminated by now?*/

      }
    });

    service.start();
    }

    // Event Listener on Button[#cancelCompareButton].onAction
    @FXML
    public void cancelCompare(ActionEvent event) {
    service.cancel();
    System.out.println("Cancel Button Pressed and mytask status is " + service.getState());
    }
```

Comment: Read Brian Goetz's article section on [Implementing cancelable tasks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/), also search for the word "cancel" in the [Task javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and read all of the matching sections to understand preferred ways of accomplishing this in a JavaFX environment.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, jewelsea. All the examples still make use of a loop to find the cancelled status.  Anyways, I changed my gui program to call a stop method and break out of the loop in the backend program. Maybe not an elegant solution, but it works. Thanks again.